# Heroku with Play Framework AND Rake

Tags: heroku, playframework, rake

I have a Play Framework app happily running on Heroku. I would like to run some rake tasks to backup the DB (OR, run anything for that matter to back up the db through a cron job on Heroku if there are other suggestions for java apps...).

So far i am striking out getting rake and Play Framework running together in the same app. As soon as I have a Gemfile there, Heroku things i am deploying a Ruby app and doesn't compile/deploy my play app. Appreciate any insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cron addon is no longer recommended on Heroku. The scheduler add on is recommended instead.

The way the documentation says to use the scheduler add on (if you are not building your apps in Rails) is to use Ruby by calling it from a script file in a bin directory. Check out the documentation here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, based on that link, it sounds like i can't run ruby from a non-rails project? So far I am not seeing an alternative to the rightAWS gem for automating backups to AWS...

Comment: the script in the example is a ruby script...its Rake you don't appear to be able to use from non-rails projects. I think it comes down to non-rails projects need to execute via a script, but that script can be any number of things...but as a ruby based platform (originally) I think they prefer ruby.

Comment: You can use the Scheduler add-on, but you can run anything.  With Play 2 the best option is to write a plain Java `static void main` and then exec that class from the Scheduler.

Comment: Thanks. That clears things up, was hoping there would be some 'magic' to run rake, but alas, no. :-)